# MySQL Select Hex() output doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can i format a SQL-Query in a HEX-SQL-Query?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM test";
   $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
   while ($ds = mysql_fetch_object($sql)){
     $text = $ds -> text;

           echo $text;
}
```

the query should look like this:

```
$query = "SELECT HEX(text) FROM test";
```

But there is an error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$text in /var/www/web207/html/... on line 45
```

Line 45 is $text = $ds -> text;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps like so:

```
$query = "SELECT HEX(text) as text FROM test";
```

Answer (score 0):

If your result-set column is *not* called `text` you obviously cannot read it from `$ds -> text`.

You have to do this:

```
$ds -> {'HEX(text)'}
```

... or simply follow Cillier's advice and give the column a proper name.